# Codeigniter 2 multiple join and where statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, codeigniter-2

**Updated code**

```
$office = $this->session->userdata('department');

$query = "SELECT `doc`.`id`, `doc`.`barcode`, `doc`.`sub`, `doc`.`source_type`, `doc`.`sender`, `doc`.`address`, `doc`.`description`, `doc`.`receipient`, `doc`.`status`, DATE_FORMAT(`doc`.`datetime_added`, '%m/%d/%Y-%h:%i %p') as datetime_added,
          (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`tag`) FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`documentId` = `doc`.`id` GROUP BY `tags`.`documentId`) as `tags`
          FROM `documents` AS `doc`
          JOIN `transactions` AS `trans` ON `doc`.`id` = `trans`.`document_id`
          JOIN `trackers` AS `track` ON `doc`.`id` = `track`.`document_id`
          WHERE `doc`.`status` = 'Processing'
          AND `track`.`action` = '1')
          AND `track`.`location` = '$office'
          ORDER BY `doc`.`id` DESC";
$go = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
var_dump($go); exit();
```

What I'm try to accomplish, is to display all documents located in our office that are **Processing** and has action **1**. Documents may have tags like memo, request, finance, etc. The output is incorrect and not showing all the records that is in our office. I think there is a problem in **WHERE** clause? What could be the culprit in my code?

Comment: You're going to need to join to a subquery which does a `GROUP_CONCAT` on the `tags` table by `id` to generate a list of all tags for each document.  I see too many problems in your code to attempt a formal answer.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen I am currently doing a custom query. I'll be updating the code later. What are the problems do you see so I could fix it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update your query by removing the single quotes surrounding 1:

```
$query = "SELECT `doc`.`id`, `doc`.`barcode`, `doc`.`sub`, `doc`.`source_type`, `doc`.`sender`, `doc`.`address`, `doc`.`description`, `doc`.`receipient`, `doc`.`status`, DATE_FORMAT(`doc`.`datetime_added`, '%m/%d/%Y-%h:%i %p') as datetime_added,
          (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`tag`) FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`documentId` = `doc`.`id` GROUP BY `tags`.`documentId`) as `tags`
          FROM `documents` AS `doc`
          JOIN `transactions` AS `trans` ON `doc`.`id` = `trans`.`document_id`
          JOIN `trackers` AS `track` ON `doc`.`id` = `track`.`document_id`
          WHERE `doc`.`status` = 'Processing'
          **AND `track`.`action` = 1)**
          AND `track`.`location` = '$office'
          ORDER BY `doc`.`id` DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("doc.id, doc.barcode, doc.sub, doc.source_type, doc.sender, doc.address, doc.description, doc.receipient, doc.status, DATE_FORMAT(doc.datetime_added, %m/%d/%Y-%h:%i %p) as datetime_added,
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag) FROM tags WHERE tags.documentId = doc.id GROUP BY tags.documentId) as tags")
      ->from("documents AS doc") 
      ->join("transactions AS trans",'doc.id=trans.document_id')
      ->join("trackers AS track",'doc.id=track.document_id')
      ->where("doc.status","Processing")
      ->andWhere("track.action","1")
      ->andWhere("doc.id",$office)
      ->order_by("doc.id", "DESC");
```